# What will be the sql query for the case insensitive comparision to display some data from the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a query to display Product Id, Product Description and Category of those products whose category name is electronics. Do case insensitive comparison.

I have implemented the sql query for the above statement.

**SELECT PRODID, PDESC, CATEGORY FROM Product WHERE
category like '%Electronics%' OR CATEGORY LIKE '%ELECTRONICS%';**

But this does not solve the above question logically.
Please Help Me guys.

Comment: The Standard SQL way is applying either UPPER or LOWER

Comment: Add proper COLLATE to the column: `WHERE category COLLATE 'correct_ci_collation_name' like '%Electronics%'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql function [`LOWER`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_lower.asp)

```
SELECT PRODID, PDESC, CATEGORY 
FROM Product 
WHERE LOWER(category) like '%electronics%';
```

Comment: You can use just `WHERE LOWER(category) = 'electronics'` as well.